# Any way to know what would work in all versions of SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

There does not seem to be standardization of SQL. For example, the code below is to query the median of the Northern Latitudes (LAT_N) from STATION table, and round the answer to 4 decimal places. It works in SQL Server, but not in MySQL.

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(((
    SELECT MAX(LAT_N)
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT LAT_N FROM STATION ORDER BY LAT_N) AS BottomHalf) 
    + (
    SELECT MIN(LAT_N)
    FROM (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT LAT_N FROM STATION ORDER BY LAT_N DESC) AS TopHalf))
/ 2, 4) AS DECIMAL(6, 4));
```

In SQL Server, the above code gives the correct output:
83.8913

But in MySQL, the same code gives run-time error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '50 PERCENT LAT_N FROM STATION ORDER BY LAT_N) AS BottomHalf) + (SELECT MIN(LAT_N' at line 1

Is there a way to know what would work for all SQL versions? That is, a common set or intersection of all SQL versions? Or can we know only after trying the program that we think should work, in all SQL versions?

Comment: Given that new features are constantly being added and old features removed it's not even possible to guarantee that code that works today in a sql dialect will still work in the next release of the same sql dialect. As for porting to other sql dialects it's probably quicker to throw code and fix than learn all possible sql dialects.

Comment: Only practical test can say does some definite query will work on some defnite SQL dialect and DBMS version.

Comment: _"There does not seem to be standardization of SQL."_ - uhhhh: the ISO would like to haev a word with you: https://www.iso.org/standard/63555.html

Comment: Note that although there are ISO/ANSI standards for SQL, that doesn't mean that every RDBMS respects them, nor does it mean that each one implements the same specifications. What is implemented, and how, can vary **significantly** between versions of an RDBMS, let alone between different products. Only the most simple of queries normally have a chance of being able to look identical between products, so 99.999~% of the time the idea of having transferable SQL is a pipe-dream.

Comment: `TOP` is proprietary TSQL syntax and the method you are using for SQL Server is quite inefficient anyway, Take a look at the methods here https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/median. `percentile_cont` is a standards compliant method but unfortunately MySQL [does not implement it](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93234)

Comment: For practical purposes there is no standardization in SQL beyond simple `SELECT` queries. Even built in functions differ either in names or little runtime subtleties. A code written for one RDBMS, may run on another RDBMS unchanged but may produce slightly different results under certain circumstances.